# How to get a paragraph from Parse.com and display it into a textView for every user that installs this application

Tags: java, android, parse-platform

I've got the basic concept of android programming using Parse.com however, I can't seem to get something back to display it into a textView. This textView should display the same text for every user that installs this application (for testing purposes). I've been through Parse.com's documentation and cant find nothing on how to put it into a textView.

So far, I have done:

```
ParseObject scripts = new ParseObject("Script");
scripts.put("Scripts to say", "**Enter Script Here**");
scripts.put("Cheatmode", false);
scripts.saveInBackground();
scripts.saveEventually();


ParseQuery<ParseObject> query = ParseQuery.getQuery("Scripts");
query.whereEqualTo("Scripts_to_say", "**Enter Script Here**");
query.findInBackground(new FindCallback<ParseObject>() {
    public void done(List<ParseObject> script, ParseException e) {
        if (e == null) {
            Log.d("Scripts", "Retrieved " + script.size() + " scripts");
        } else {
            Log.d("script", "Error: " + e.getMessage());
        }
    }
});
```

Comment: Have you tried anything at all?

Comment: Yes, i have successfully created the fields in Parse cloud, I have also entered the text into that field however I cant get it into a textview to show the same text on every device.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe something like this (haven't tested it)

```
ParseObject scripts = new ParseObject("Script");
scripts.put("Scripts to say", "**Enter Script Here**");
scripts.put("Cheatmode", false);
scripts.saveInBackground(); // or scripts.saveEventually(); depending whether you want to use the object immediately or not, don't use both.


ParseQuery<ParseObject> query = ParseQuery.getQuery("Script");
query.whereEqualTo("Scripts to say", "**Enter Script Here**");
query.getFirstInBackground(new GetCallback<ParseObject>() {
    public void done(ParseObject script, ParseException e) {
        if (script != null) {
            Log.d("Object retrieved.");
            String yourString = script.getString("Scripts_to_say");
            //NOW ADD IT TO YOUR EDITTEXT HERE           
        } else {
            Log.d("Empty query");
        }
    }
});
```

Comment: Agree, except if you are only searching for a single object, you are better of using the first method rather than find.

Comment: Indeed, will fix my answer.

Comment: Thank you very much Manuel, one question. You said not to use xxxx.saveInBackground(); and xxxx.saveEventually(); together, why?

Comment: Both methods are used to save the record to the DB, so you don't need to save the object twice. The difference between them is `saveInBackground();` will attempt to save the record directly to the DB using a background Thread and `saveEventually();` will save the object whenever a connection is available, storing the object in the local file system for the time being. For further info read the [Parse API](http://parse.com/docs/android/api/)

Comment: Thank you again Manuel for clearing that up for me! Really helped me out! I made a few changes to the code you gave me and now anything I input on Parse.com comes on my textView automatically.